# What is the difference between implementing hook_url_inbound_alter() and hook_url_outbound_alter(), and using a path alias?

Tags: 7, uri

In Drupal 7, a module could implement [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) and [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) to rewrite URLs used in Drupal. The same effect could be obtained with path aliases. The only difference is that for path aliases that are someway dynamic, you would need a module that adds a path alias every time there is the need. That is what the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module does.

Is there any difference between the two approaches (implementing those hooks, and using path aliases)? Is there any reason to prefer one approach to the other one?
Is there any performance difference between the two approaches?

The only difference I can see is that with those hooks there could not be the need of accessing the database (depending on how the hooks are implemented). Is that the only difference, or are there more differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `hook_url_outbound_alter()` has some potential performance issues because it is executed by every single URL on a page via the [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/7) function. This means a module could implement `hook_url_outbound_alter()` with some complex and slow code that is called 100's of times per page.

Also [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) allows a link's `$options`, including its query string, to be altered, which is impossible to do to path aliases and a very useful feature. For example, I have altered internal RSS URLs to point to their respective Feedburner and iTunes URLs.

Conceptually, the Path module should be calling the `hook_url_*_alter()` hooks but it is probably slightly faster to have the `drupal_get_path_alias()` calls directly in `url()`.

My personal conclusion is when possible use the built-in path system, but for most special circumstances you will have to use the `hook_url_*_alter()` hooks.